# calculate area bounded by region

Tags: calculus, integration

suppose ,that we are going to find are of
 $x*y=4$
bounded by $x=1$  and $x=4$ and $y=0$

generaly  as i know are of function $y=f(x)$ bounded by $x=a$    and  $x=b$ is given by

$A=\int(f(x)), x=a,x=b $; so in this case $y=4/x$   it's integral would be $4*ln(x)$,now if we put variables we will get $4*ln(4)-4*ln(1)$=$5.545-4*0=5.545$
but because  this is bounded by $y=0$,is there any place where i should use this?for example in intersection or  anything else?thanks guys

Comment: *Draw a picture*, and think about the region you are asked to find the area of. It is below (or on) $y=4/x$, above (or on) the $x$-axis ($y=0)$, from $x=1$ to $x=4$. Totally standard area problem.  You got the right answer. The reason you were unsure is probably that you looked first for a formula, and not a picture.

Comment: you are right @ André Nicolas thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area under $xy=4$ (i.e. bounded below by $y=0$) for $x\in[1,4]$ would be $$\int_1^4\frac4xdx=4\,\Bigl.\ln x\Bigr|_1^4=4\Bigl(\ln 4-\ln 0\Bigr)=4\ln 4\approx5.545177444$$

Comment: aaa sorry  i have put 3 instead of 4,sorry